# JQuery get value from the cell <td> before this <td><input>, jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have this html code:
[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6x7wn/3/)

```
<table align="center">
    <td align="center" colspan="5">Table</td>
    <tbody>
        <tr> // Table Headings (Not important, removed)
        </tr>
             // First Row (of many)            
        <tr>
            <td>Cell 1</td>              // Cell 1
            <td>Cell 2</td>              // Cell 2

            // This is the cell I want the price in
            <td class="unitprice" align="center">2.99</td> // Cell 3 <-- I want this value

            // Onkeyup of this input box, get the value in cell 3 into a var.
            <td align="center">
            <input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" size="2" value="1" onkeyup="getValues();" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"/>
            </td>

            <td class="totalprice" align="center">TOTAL PRICE</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am using this javascript to get the value from the "qty" text box,

```
  function getValues(e)
  {
      var qty = e.value; // Get me the value in qty
      // This is what I tried
      //var Something = $(this).parent().find("td.unitprice").html(); 
      alert(Something); // Does not work
  }
```

**Basically**

**Onblur of input[QTY], get the value of qty, get the price next to it, and update it into the div class (totalprice) FOR THAT ROW ONLY.**

**I have dozens of records so this function should be for that specific row the input was changed for.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    var _parent = $(this).parent();
    _parent.next().html(Number(_parent.prev().html()) * Number($(this).val()));
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/6x7wn/9/

Uses this resource: http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: This works, but only on the second change of the input box, ie: if i refresh the page, and change row 1 input, it wont work, until I change it for a second time, then it works. im using it in a function right now.

Comment: The fiddle works on the first attempt for me. Shouldn't be too hard to emulate the logic. What did you change?

Comment: the fiddle works fine, but when I use my localhost, it doesnt work first time, only on second+ click. I didnt change a single thing, it worked first time, except for this issue. How would I load this on dom ready, so it runs it once (when it wont do nothing), and ready for the user to use when they change the field.

Comment: changing click to live shouldn't break anything. I'm assuming your syntax is off - make sure it's like this: `$('selector').live('click',function(){...`

Comment: Adding to dom ready is simply putting the observer inside a dom ready function `$(function(){  $('selector').live('click',function(){..}); });`

Comment: changing to live didnt work, i'll try this on a live server and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/6x7wn/15/).

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use jQuery then this should work:

```
$('#qty').keyup(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6x7wn/6/

Also, the jsFiddle you linked was not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/6x7wn/8/

and my two cents... use the e.srcElement to get where you came from ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this using the id selector

```
$('#qty').keyup(function() {
  alert("...");
});
```